# Override default value in a map

Tags: terraform

Is there any way to override the default value set as locals in the module and the invocation part?

In module default value looks like this:

**module.tf**

```
locals {

  default_instance = {
    "instance_1" = {
      instance_id        = "test_1"
      instance_type     = "t2.medium"
      ami                = "ami-1234567"
      instance_config        = {
        ebs = {
          "xvdb" = 20
        }
     },
    "instance_2" = {
      instance_id        = "test_2"
      instance_type     = "t2.small"
      ami                = "ami-7654321"
      instance_config        = {
        ebs = {
          "xvdb" = 30
        }
     },
.....
  }

variable "instance" {
  type = map(object{})
}
```

and in module calling part would like to override any value depending on the case, for example:

```
module "ec2" {
  source = "./module.tf"

  instance = local.instance

}


locals {

  instance = {
    "instance_1" = {
      instance_type     = "m5.xlarge"
      instance_config        = {
        ebs = {
          "xvdb" = 100
        }
     }
  }
```

Or is there any better way to handle this

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "invocation part"? In the parent module?

Comment: @Marcin, in the module calling part override values that comes from the parent module

Comment: You've showed two `locals` blocks. Its not clear how they are related? They are in the same module?

Comment: @Marcin, I've made some changes to the post, maybe right it will make sense to you. In the module in locals, I specify the default values. Then if needed values need to be changed in calling part

Comment: So you have multiple default values? `instance_1`, `instance_2` and so on?

Comment: Also `instance = local.instance` this will not work, as your variable is `type = map(string)`. Your `local.instance` is of different type.

Comment: @Marcin, Yes, I might have several instances 1,2,3.....

`type = map(object{})` this is correct type I would think